Why ParseExact is not converting my variable to DateTime
I am trying to convert a string value to a Datetime value with powershell, but I getting this error:
Excepción al llamar a "ParseExact" con los argumentos "3": "No se puede reconocer la cadena como valor DateTime válido."
En línea: 6 Carácter: 1
+ $CertDate = [DateTime]::ParseExact("$Cert", 'MMM-d-HH:mm:ss-yyyy', $n ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException

This is my code:
$certificatePath = "C:\Users\user\certificate.pem"
$opensslPath = "C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.exe"

$Cert = & $opensslPath x509 -in  $certificatePath -noout -enddate
$Cert = $Cert.split("=")[1]
$Cert = $Cert.replace(" ","-")
$Cert = $Cert.replace("--","-")
$Cert = $Cert.replace("-GMT","")
$CertDate = [DateTime]::ParseExact("$Cert", 'MMM-d-HH:mm:ss-yyyy', $null)
$CurrentDate = Get-Date
$DateTime = $CertDate - $CurrentDate
$Date = $DateTime.Days

The output of the variable $cert is:
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $Cert
Oct-8-11:05:03-2025

And the variable $Cert is a String Type:
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $cert.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                                                    
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                                                    
True     True     String                                   System.Object 

The $Cert output match with the format indicated in the ParseExact: 'MMM-d-HH:mm:ss-yyyy'
Any idea of what I am doing wrong?
Thanks and BR!
Tried different formts and doesn't worked

Could you please add the output from $cert | Format-Hex to your question? Try changing
the $null argument to [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture. It should work assuming there are no invisible chars that could be causing this issue.

You have the hour and the year backwards : 'MMM-d-HH:mm:ss-yyyy'

Try passing [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture instead of $null as the 3rd argument

I can never remember exactly how PowerShell works with CultureInfos, but for reference, $es = [system.globalization.cultureinfo]::new("es-ES"); $d = [datetime] '2024-09-13' $d.ToString('MMM-d-HH:mm:ss-yyyy', $es) gives sep.-13-00:00:00-2024 (note the . after the sep). If it's defaulting to es-ES for ParseExact on your machine then the "missing" . is why it's failing, in which case @SantiagoSquarzon's suggestion of [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture should parse the sample string you've given - ymmv in practice though :-)...

Assuming there are no invisible characters that could be causing this issue, by simply changing the Provider argument from $null to InvariantCulture the issue should be solved.
& {
    $Cert = 'Oct-8-11:05:03-2025'
    [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
        [cultureinfo]::GetCultureInfo('es-AR')

    [DateTime]::ParseExact($Cert, 'MMM-d-HH:mm:ss-yyyy', [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)
    # Correctly parses into: `miércoles, 8 de octubre de 2025 11:05:03`
}

In ParseExact Remarks section you can read the following:

If provider is null, the CultureInfo object that corresponds to the current culture is used.

In Spanish culture a month in the MMM format would end with a ., i.e.: Oct.. This is why using $null fails to parse and also this is proven by, if you add the . it parses correctly:
& {
    # With the `.` after `Oct` this parses corretly in Spanish culture
    $Cert = 'Oct.-8-11:05:03-2025'
    [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
        [cultureinfo]::GetCultureInfo('es-AR')

    [DateTime]::ParseExact($Cert, 'MMM-d-HH:mm:ss-yyyy', $null)
}


Thanks for all the help!
Replacing "$null" to "[cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture" solved my issue.
BR,
